# Path animation curve issue

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints, path

I have a bone constrained to follow a path. the pivot point is at the end of this blue line when I expected it to be the origin. I messed around with settings and positions and couldn't figure out how to make the origin the pivot point.
[image: problem]

As a result this is what my animation does...
[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

THE BLEND
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7y3nedlsgsz4oc/carwashdoora.blend?dl=0

Comment: Upload the blend. :)

Comment: uploaded the blend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by positioning the bone at the start of the path, where you want the object too start. I know, seems to simple, but that will fix it.